Feedback on spaCy NER Model Annotations for Recipe Ingredient Extraction
I'm training a spaCy NER model to specifically identify and categorize lines of ingredients in recipes. The goal is to accurately extract ingredients along with their quantities, units, and preparation instructions from various recipes. Below is an outline of how I'm annotating the data:
Spanning Labels

Quantity: Digits related to a unit (e.g., "2", "3/4")
Ingredient: Actual ingredient name (e.g., "sugar", "milk")
Measurement Unit: The unit of measurement (e.g., "cup", "tbsp")
Instruction: Preparation instructions (e.g., "finely diced", "divided")

Relationship Labels

quantity_of: Relates the span label quantity to the ingredient
action_to: Relates the span label instruction to the ingredient
unit_of: Relates the span label measurement unit to the quantity

I've provided two examples: one simple ingredient line and one complex one.
Simple Line
Complex Line
I'm seeking feedback on a couple of points:

Annotation Overkill: Are there too many categories or overly detailed annotations for effective learning and practical application? Should some categories be merged or omitted?
Training Data Volume: How much annotated data is typically recommended to achieve a robust model in this type of NER task? I want to ensure the model is reliable across various recipe formats.

What I've tried:
I trained a model using a similar labeling set-up, minus the relationship labels and the "Measurement Unit" spanning label. I trained the model on about 700 samples from random recipes. The results were subpar; the model had a hard time identifying certain aspects, specifically in situations where the quantities and their units were not next to each other (e.g. 3 garlic cloves)
